# Using ASP.NET MVC RedirectResult class in custom authentication filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-custom-filter

I have simple custom authentication filter:

```
public class MyAuthAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{

    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("Account/Login");
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

There are also HomeController with Index action method and AccountController with Login action method. The Index action method uses my custom filter. When I try to call Index action method, my filter intercepts code execution and make redirect to Home/Account/Login url. Why does it happen? I expected a call of Login action in AccountController.

Answer (score 0):

You are being redirected because you don't have a condition in your filter that ensures the user is not authenticated before redirecting.

A filter runs on *every* request. It is up to you to put branching logic within the filter to make it conditional.

```
public class MyAuthAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{

    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("Account/Login");
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Reference: http://jameschambers.com/2013/11/working-with-iauthenticationfilter-in-the-mvc-5-framework/

Comment: The solution is very simple. When we specify url, it's necessary to add "/" or "~/". Condition doesn't influences on code execution.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the way you have given the URL i.e. `"Account/Login"`. 
When you do not start the URL with `"/"`, it will check for the `action method` in the current controller.
To redirect to the correct controller and method use - `"/APPLICATION_NAME/CONTROLLER_NAME/METHOD_NAME"`